# Property Replacement in Maven Site Content

Tags: maven, properties, maven-descriptor

I'm generating maven site content using the [site plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin-2.3/).   I want to have a little table that shows my maven group id, artifact id, parent info, etc on the module.  I don't see a plugin for it, so I was going to use the [APT format](http://maven.apache.org/doxia/references/apt-format.html) and create a content page with a table for it.  The [documentation says I can use property replacement](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin-2.3/examples/sitedescriptor.html) in the site descriptor via ${project.name} etc.  This fails when i use it in both the descriptor and in my index.apt file.  Has anybody seen this done or know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The mvn site command generates a Project Summary page which has this information on it.  Does that work for you?

For example, when I execute mvn site, get an output here target/site/project-summary.html where the page has a section like so:

```
Build Information

Field       Value
GroupId     com.a.b
ArtifactId  myapp
Version     1.01.13-SNAPSHOT
Type        jar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create pages which use placeholder like ${project.version} etc. you need to use index.apt.vm (velocity files) wher the replacement works. But for the information you have asked the solution which has been described (project-summary.html) is the right way cause it's automatically generated.